# Cannot find public method in test (Uncompilable code) in Netbeans (but works from command line)

Tags: java, junit, netbeans

I want to test a public method from a class that already has tests.

```
public class LocalDb {
  private final static LocalDb INSTANCE = new LocalDb();

 public synchronized static LocalDb getInstance() {
   ...
   return INSTANCE;
 }
 
 private LocalDb() {
    }

 public boolean getSomething(){
}

 public void justForTest(){
       
 }

}
```

However in my test, when I do `LocalDb.getInstance().justForTest()` I get `symbol not found` whereas `LocalDb.getInstance().getSomething()` is found and other tests within this Test Class run fine.

The only difference between the two is that getSomething was created months ago, whereas justForTest has just been created. No new method can be "found" in test class, whereas it can be found anywhereelse in code.

Edit : If I use from the command line `mvn -Dtest=LocalDbTest#testJustForTest test` I don't get the "Uncompilable code : cannot find symbol" error I get in Netbeans and the test succeeds.

I also tried to delete the project "target" directory, to "clean and build" the project, to restart Netbeans, to reboot the computer.

What is happening ? I am using Netbeans 12.8.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding your project?

Comment: "when I do localDb.justForTest()" sounds like you call these methods from a different class. How is this different class related to `LocalDb`? Is it in a different project?

Comment: @QBrute Yes I did (clean and buil)!

Comment: @f1sh I use a singleton pattern (see my edit). THis is the same project and the same object. I wanted to summarize the issue but I meant `LocalDb localDb = new LocalDb()` and now with the edit it is `localDb = LocalDb.getInstance()`. Is it clearer :) ?